# Custom context processor can't be found?

Tags: django

While trying to deploy my Django app I keep getting this error about my custom context processors:

Error importing request processor module context_processors: "No module named context_processors"

In settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    "app.context_processors.media_url",
    "app.context_processors.static_url",    
)
```

my context processor is djangoapp/app/context_processors.py (**init**.py included):

```
from django.conf import settings

def media_url(request):
    return {'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL}

def static_url(request):
    return {'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL}
```

Worked fine in the development server but not when I tried to deploy it on apache + mod_wsgi.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using mod_wsgi? if so what's in your wsgi file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `"djangoapp.app.context_processors.media_url` but I don't get it why you include `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` sencond time. `django.core.context_processors.media` context processor contains `MEDIA_URL` already and `django.core.context_processors.static` contains `STATIC_URL`.